# How can I add custom client side validation to validation that was generated from annotations in MVC5 VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I have added a number of annotations to do simple required field validation in a modal form.  Now I need to do a somewhat convoluted check for uniqueness on a couple of the fields involved.

**I want to avoid using a custom annotation to do this** as the fields that require validation within the model require extra information that does not exist in the model.

I want to be able to add a new rule to the existing validation via script.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get both the new rule and the existing ones to work at the same time.

If I do the following, then *only the new rule* gets applied, all the existing rules (required fields etc.) disappear.

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("uniqueresourceid", 
        function(value, element, options) {
            return ResourceIDValidation(options.resourceSet, value, options.originalresourceidpropertyname);
        }, "This resource ID is already inuse.");   

    var validator = $('#InstitutionModalForm').validate();

    $('#Institution_NameResourceID').rules("add", {
        uniqueresourceid: {
            resourceSet: "Institutions",
            resourceId: $('#NameResourceID').val(),
            oldResourceId: "OriginalNameResourceID"
        }
    });

    function ResourceIDValidation(ResourceSet, ResourceID, OldResourceIDField) {
        var valid = false;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("ValidateResourceID", "Admin")",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                ResourceSet: ResourceSet,
                ResourceID: ResourceID,
                OldResourceID: $('#' + OldResourceIDField).val(),
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                 valid = result;
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.log(data);
                valid = false;
            }
        });
        return valid;
    }
```

If I remove the 'var validator =...' line, then *only the original* validation (required fields etc.) fires.

I can't see any reason why this shouldn't be possible, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

I'm not really clear on how the unobtrusive stuff does it's magic, but shouldn't there be a way to hook into whatever validator is being generated by the server side annotations so that I can add a new rule in the JS?

Comment: No this will not work. Manually adding rules and calling `.validate()` does not play well with `jquery.validation.unotrusive` (which adds the rules etc based on the `data-val` attributes generated by the HtmlHelpers). You should be creating a validation attribute that implements `IClientValidatable` and apply it to your model property. Without knowing exactly what you trying to do, impossible to give you an answer.

Comment: I think I set about doing something I probably shouldn't have by including a model as a property of a viewmodel.  The viewmodel contains a necessary part of the validation check, while the model contains the actual item that needs to be validated.  Because of this, I am unable to decorate the model property because it needs information from the viewmodel in order to be able to validate it.  I will update my question in the morning to attempt to clarify further.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you mentioned that the rules are based on data-val attributes, is there a way for me to leverage that to accomplish what I'm after?  Can I add custom data-val attributes to make use of the added rules?

Comment: What you should be doing is creating you own `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable` buts its a bit unclear what exactly you trying to validate. Your first problem lies in the fact your not really using a view model (its just a model that contains a property which is a data model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is *possible* but I can see some very important reasons why you **wouldn't want to do this**.

Most importantly, this creates a **client side validation only**.  This means if someone nefariously submits the form, or if they don't have JS enabled, that **your server side code will not do this validation and probably break**.

In addition to that, it makes your code harder to maintain as the validation is not handily visible in your code as it would be with an annotation.

While it is probably a **very bad idea to do this**, this is how you could make it happen.  Adding this code above the "addMethod" caused it to validate as I initially intended.

```
$('#NameResourceID').attr("data-val", "true");
$('#NameResourceID').attr("data-val-uniqueresourceid", "Resource ID must be unique.");
$('#NameResourceID').attr("data-val-uniqueresourceid-resourceset","institutions");
$('#NameResourceID').attr("data-val-uniqueresourceid-originalresourceidpropertyname","OriginalNameResourceID");
```

**Do this instead**: Implement a custom validation annotation as Stephen Muecke suggested in the question comments.  It was more work, but in the end is far better practice.  [This](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/) was the most helpful (to me) tutorial I could find on the subject.